# Proving that a set is disconnected

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

I would like some hints with items iii and iv within the question below.

Prove that a set $S$ is disconnected if and only if there exist sets $A$ and $B$ contained within the metric space $X$ such that:

i.  $A$ and $B$ are nonempty

ii. $S=A\cup B$

iii.    $\operatorname{Cl}(A) \cap B= \varnothing$

iv. $A \cap \operatorname{Cl}(B)=\varnothing$

Comment: What is your definition of disconnected?

Comment: A metric space X is disconnected if there exists sets U,V contained within X such that U and V are open, U intersect V = null set, X=UuV, and U does not equal the null set which does not equal V.

Comment: So at which direction of the proof do you have problems?

Comment: @StefanH. I want to work on the left to right direction first, so I'm having problems showing that a disconnected set implies that the Closure(A) intersect B=null set and A intersect Closure(B)=null set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be disconnected, i.e. $S=U\sqcup V$, where $U,V\ne\emptyset$ and $U$ and $V$ are relatively open in $S$. To show that $\mathrm{cl}(A)\cap B=∅$, note that if $b\in B$, then since $B$ is relatively open in $S$, there is an $r>0$ such that each $s\in S$ with $d(b,s)<r$ is a point in $B$, hence not in $A$. But any $y$ outside of $S$ with $d(b,y)<r$ cannot be in $A$ as $A\subset S$. This shows that $b$ is not a limit point of $A$.

Comment: What is B'? Is it an open ball?

Comment: @Study: $B'$ is just an open set. The open sets in the subspace topology on $S$ are the intersections of $S$ with the open sets in the whole space $X$. That is either by definition of *subspace topology*, or, in case you defined the topology on $S$ via the metric, it must be proven. I don't know which definition you are using.

Comment: We do not make any reference to topological definitions in my real analysis class. I do not know the term subspace topology.

Comment: @Study: Ah, okay, so you are using the restricted metric on $S$ to define open sets in $S$? Where an $r$-ball $B^S_r(x)$ around a point $x\in S$ relative to $S$ is the set $\{y\in S\mid d(x,y)<r\}$?

Comment: Correct, though I don't think we call the restricted metric.

Comment: @Study: I have edited my answer to make it more "metric" and less "topological" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hints for #3:

$Cl(A) \cap B = \emptyset$. 
Let $A'$ be the set of limit points of $A$. 
That means $(A \cup A') \cap B = \emptyset$ so $(A \cap B) \cup (A' \cap B) = \emptyset$.

Also, $x \in A$, where $A$ is closed, its complement is open, and $x \not\in B \subset A^c$. Thus $B$ is open.

The same could be generalized for #4. Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: I understand what you have written, but how does this imply that the closure of A intersect B equals the null set? A is a subset of its closure. A and Cl(A) have different limits points (and all of Cl(A) limits points are contained within Cl(A).)

Comment: By definition the set is separated (see Rudin, connected sets) and thus not connected. (disconnected)

Comment: A set is connected if it is not a union of separated sets.

Comment: We do not use Rudin. We use Rosenlicht. I understand that Rudin is better.

Comment: So....Rudin is wrong all of a sudden? I was just referencing him.